# Running process interactively (like compilation) but without parsing

Tags: compilation, process

Is there any command which let me observe output of async-called process (just like <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>compile</kbd>), but does not try to parse output buffer?

Background: for quite a lot of non-compilation tasks (hg push, python some_sample_script, unzip big_file.zip and much more...) I tend to prefer

<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>compile</kbd>  «command»

to both

<kbd>M-!</kbd> «command»

and

<kbd>M-!</kbd> «command» <kbd>&</kbd>

The reason is simple: M-x compile does not block Emacs, let me observe command progress in a buffer (including <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> and search), always leaves output in solid non-disappearing buffer even if output happens to be short and can be safely <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> in case of problems.

There is one problem, though: compilation parses command output, what brings unneeded coloring, sometimes causes confusing navigation, and - what is worst - introduces performance penalty on long outputs.

So, is there anything what would spawn process exactly as <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>compile</kbd>, but leave output buffer as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-&</kbd> Runs `async-shell-command`